# Custom class in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I've created a custom class inside the `app/Helpers` folder.

I want to access it in views like `Helper::someMethod()`. I tried to bind it in `IoC`. But couldn't get it working. The following is my **Helper** class:

```
class ApplicationHelpers {
    public function me() {
        return "this is me!";
    }
}
```

This is how I bind it in the AppServiceProvider class in register method.

```
$this->app->make('App\Helpers\ApplicationHelpers');
```

And this is how I want to access in view.

```
<div class="title m-b-md">
   {{ ApplicationHelpers::me() }}
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add an alias on config/app.php and composer dump-autoload, then you can use that alias on view.

Comment: Please note with whichever answer you go with, you will need to set your helper function to a static function using `public static function me()`. This will allow the `::` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Inside config/app.php aliases array add this line

```
'Helper' => App\Helpers\Helper::class, //your class path
```

then use `composer dump-autoload`

Then you can use helper function in view like this

```
{{Helper::userInfo()}} or {{Helper->userInfo()}}
```

Helper is alias name and function. use :: or -> based on function definition.

Comment: @WebArtisan what do you think about this article http://jamalabdulnasir.com/incorporating-custom-class-in-laravel-application

Comment: Same solution as I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not register the class anywhere, you have to include the namespace. So it would look like this:

```
<div class="title m-b-md">
   {{ \App\Helpers\ApplicationHelpers::me() }}
</div>
```

Or you can create an alias in your [`config/app.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L189) and then call the class directly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add simple functions helpers you can also edit your composer.json file and add the path to your helper file

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Http/ApplicationHelpers.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

where you can declare simple function such as me()

```
function me() {
    return "this is me!";
}
```

then call `composer dump-autoload`
so you can simply call

```
<div class="title m-b-md">
   {{ me() }}
</div>
```